# Add a highscore system that's saves the data

Tags: c#, save, store

I was wondering how I would go about creating a high score system. I've made a simple game with score's, but I want to have the highscores saved in a file, so when the application runs you can see the high score with the name.
My code for the game so far, if needed:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Guess_the_number_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int randomNumber;
        int score;

        Random random;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            random = new Random();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            score = 0;
            label1.Text = score.ToString();
        }

        private void buttonCheckGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            randomNumber = random.Next(0, 10);

            if (Convert.ToInt32(textboxGuess.Text) == randomNumber)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your Guessed Correctly! The Number Is: " + textboxGuess.Text);
                score += 10;
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(textboxGuess.Text) < randomNumber)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Number Is Larger Than: " + textboxGuess.Text);
                score -= 2;
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(textboxGuess.Text) > randomNumber)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Number Is Smaller Than: " + textboxGuess.Text);
                score -= 2;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your Guessed Incorrectly. The Random Number Is Not: " + textboxGuess.Text);
            }
            label1.Text = score.ToString();
        }

        private void buttonScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your score is " + score);
        }

        private void listScore_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe try adding a using for `System.IO`?  That's the simplest way I know to manipulate files...

Comment: As soon as you move past saving one piece of data, the XML method is the easiest.

Answer (score 3):

The way I would do it is to serialize it to XML. This will allow you to save several high scores, in addition, storing other info, such as the player's initials. To do this, first make a class like this:

```
[Serializable()]
public class HighScore {
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
}

public List<HighScore> _highScores = new List<HighScore>();
```

You will add all your scores to the collection class:

```
// To save a high score
var score = new HighScore() { Score = 100, Initials = 'MAJ' };
_highScores.Add(score);
// ... add more scores if needed
```

Then when your application exits (or whenever you want to save the high scores), you serialize your high scores to XML:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(_highScores.GetType(), "HighScores.Scores");
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("highscores.xml", false))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, _highScores);
}
```

Finally, when your application loads (or whenever), you use this code to deserialize the XML back into a high scores collection:

```
// To Load the high scores
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(_entities.GetType(), "HighScores.Scores");
object obj;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("highscores.xml"))
{
    obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader.BaseStream);
}
_highScores = (List<HighScore>)obj;
```

Comment: This is the way to go. You can add as many properties to the `HighScore` class as you want and not worry about extra code each time to parse the new property. Adding a `DateTime` for example.

Comment: In addition, the Serializer and Deserializer will take of parsing the file. You won't need to worry about parsing the high scores if you store it, in say, a text file.

Answer (score 1):

For loading the best score use the function below

```
using(System.IO.StreamReader sr=new System.IO.StreamReader("fileYouHaveSavedTheScore.txt")
     this.label1.Text=sr.ReadLine();
```

For saving the score you can do something like this:

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("fileYouHaveSavedTheScore.txt");
if(Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine())<Convert.ToInt32(this.label1.Text)
{
    sr.Close();
    using(System.IO.StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter("fileYouHaveSavedTheScore.txt",false))
        sw.WriteLine(this.label1.Text);
}
```

**EDIT**

Don't use all that `Convert.ToInt32(string)`, it's better use the method `int.TryParse(string, int out)`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f02979c7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can find the reference of this method

Comment: This will indeed persist the score to the file system, but once you want to extend past one element, it can get ugly trying to parse lines out.

Answer (score 0):

I used two simple methods for saving a High Score that is used in a game.
These two methods are using TextWriter and TextReader. It's quite simple and might help you or at least help guide you. Hope this helps, link below. Btw I am creating a mashup of Galaga and Space Invaders and this is where it came in handy for me.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsq3H13woTvEuUNQD0ch1Yw?